# How to add DKIM signature to email header in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework to develop website.

In the development process, I am getting an issue to add DKIM signature in the receiving email headers. I have tried many ways to get the solution but still struggling with them.

So could you please provide me any solution for this. Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses ZF 2, there is a module to help https://github.com/fastnloud/zf2-dkim